# Relay type identification

Tags: relay

[image]

I have this relay from an old clock. I wanted to replace it but I can not find any replacement because I can't identify the relay type, it seems to be an odd long armature relay. Tried everything on google and on various parts supplier sites but haven't got any luck.

Comment: it looks like a standard relay, but without the plastic case. If you know the voltage it runs at, and the nominal current, you can replace it with pretty much anything within that spec, as it is unlikely that you will be able to find a direct replacement for that one

Comment: Is it even a relay? I'm guessing that's a bell-ringing solenoid.

Comment: Why do you want to replace the solenoid? It looks fine to me.

Comment: I don't see any relay contacts.  I thinkI'd call it a solenoid or actuator.  Does that long arm hit a bell, or cause some other mechanical action?

Comment: You can probably repair this solenoid if it is not working - a broken or burned wire is about the only thing that can wrong, and yours doesn't look burned.  Try checking for continuity.

Comment: Spehro Pefhany - Because it has a shorted winding.

Comment: Peter Bennett - It closes a contact through the long armature to ground, when the spring which powers the movement of the clock unwinds and needs to be rewound, basically the relay/solenoid gives the spring a kick.